# which image is clicked jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: How to determine which <li> tag was clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808189/jquery-how-to-determine-which-li-tag-was-clicked)

I have a `div` with images inside it and I want to know which image is clicked, whether it's the 1st, 2nd or 3rd.

```
<div class="imageholder">
    <span><img src="image1"></span>
    <span><img src="image2"></span>
    <span><img src="image3"></span>
</div>
```

How can we get this in jQuery?

Comment: Take a look in this question, as it is basically the same one only for `<li>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808189/jquery-how-to-determine-which-li-tag-was-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".imageholder span img").click(function(){
var k1 = $(".imageholder span img").index(this);
alert(k1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3dGB/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".imageholder img").click(function(){
    var image = $(this).attr("src").replace("image","")
    alert(image);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the image itself, not it's position in the `div`, the following will work for you:

```
$(".imageholder img").click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UEFht/)

To get the images ordering position in the `div`, use this:

```
$(".imageholder img").click(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/UEFht/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".imageholder img").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work :)

```
$('.imageholder').find('img').click(function(){
    var thisImg = $(this).attr('src');
    alert(thisImg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get which image in order is clicked i.e. wanna get the index you can use Jquery index function.

```
   $('.imageholder img').click(function(){
       alert($(this).index());
   });
```